# How do I replace Bower with Yarn --flat with nested dependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, yarnpkg, es6-modules

Bower is no longer maintained and the recommendation is to move to npm.

However, npm is designed for Node and has a nested dependency model that's completely unsuitable for the web.

So (for instance) given `component-X` and `component-Y` that both need `library-A` Bower would download something like:

```
/bower-components
    /library-A
    /component-X
    /component-Y
```

While npm produces:

```
/node_modules
    /component-X
        /node_modules
            /library-A
    /component-Y
        /node_modules
            /library-A
```

As this is a web application multiple copies of `library-A` are a significant problem - we need to load it exactly once.

Potentially Yarn solves this with [`yarn install --flat`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-flat) as that flattens the structure and has a [resolution mechanism](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) for different versions.

However, the nested references inside the components don't point to the new location. For instance, inside `component-X` there will be a line like:

```
import {moduleB} from 'library-A/module-B.js';
```

This now fails, it needs to point to the new *flattened* location:

```
import {moduleB} from '../library-A/module-B.js';
```

It seems that without this change `yarn install --flat` is pretty useless, as nested dependencies will always be lost.

How do I make Yarn update these resolutions as it flattens?

Is there another way? I realise a custom Gulp/Grunt/Webpack/Rollup task can do it, but that seems like a workaround for something supposedly obsolete Bower did out of the box.

Comment: Check out the github discussion [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2134). Some of the people commenting seems to recommend using common libraries as a `peerDependency`.

Comment: @AndrewL cheers - I realise I can rewrite all these dependencies with WebPack, but really that's my fallback. It seems messy when Bower just got it right in the first place.